# Sort the basic of Number of documents in ElasticSearch

Tags: elasticsearch

I am saving user relations in ES Index

i.e

{'id' => 1, 'User_id_1' => '2001', 'relation' => 'friend', 'User_id_2' => '1002'}
{'id' => 2, 'User_id_1' => '2002', 'relation' => 'friend', 'User_id_2' => '1002'}

{'id' => 3, 'User_id_1' => '2002', 'relation' => 'friend', 'User_id_2' => '1001'}
{'id' => 4, 'User_id_1' => '2003', 'relation' => 'friend', 'User_id_2' => '1003'}

no suppose i want to get the user_id_2 who has most friends,

in above case its 1002 as 2001, and 2002 are its friends. (Count = 2)

I just can't figure out the query

Thanks.

EDIT:

Well as suggested by @imotov, term facets is very good choice, but

The problem I have is 2 Indexes

1st index is for saving the main docs and 2nd index for saving the relations

now problem is

Suppose I have 100 USER Docs in my main index, only 50 of them has made relations, so I'll have only 50 USER Docs in my relationship index

So when i implement the "term facet", it sorts the results and gives the correct output i want, but I am missing those left 50 users who don't have any relations yet, i need them in my final output after the 50 sorted users.

Answer (score 1):

First of all, we need to ensure that relationships saved in ES are unique. It can be done by replacing arbitrary ids with ids constructed from user_id_1, relation and user_id_2. We also need to make sure that analyzer for user_ids doesn't produce multiple tokens. If ids are strings, they have to be indexed not_analyzed. With these two conditions satisfied, we can simply use [terms facet](http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/reference/api/search/facets/terms-facet.html) query for the field user_id_2 on the result list limited by relation:friend. This query will retrieve top user_id_2 ids sorted by number of occurrences in the index. All together it could look something like this:

```
curl -XPUT http://localhost:9200/relationships -d '{
    "mappings" : {
        "relation" : {
            "_source" : {"enabled" : false },
            "properties" : {
                "user_id_1": { "type": "string", "index" : "not_analyzed"},
                "relation": { "type": "string", "index" : "not_analyzed"},
                "user_id_2": { "type": "string", "index" : "not_analyzed"}
            }
        }
    }
}'

curl -XPUT http://localhost:9200/relationships/relation/2001-friend-1002 -d '{"user_id_1": "2001", "relation":"friend", "user_id_2": "1002"}'
curl -XPUT http://localhost:9200/relationships/relation/2002-friend-1002 -d '{"user_id_1": "2002", "relation":"friend", "user_id_2": "1002"}'
curl -XPUT http://localhost:9200/relationships/relation/2002-friend-1001 -d '{"user_id_1": "2002", "relation":"friend", "user_id_2": "1001"}'
curl -XPUT http://localhost:9200/relationships/relation/2003-friend-1003 -d '{"user_id_1": "2003", "relation":"friend", "user_id_2": "1003"}'
curl -XPOST http://localhost:9200/relationships/_refresh
echo


curl -XGET 'http://localhost:9200/relationships/relation/_search?pretty=true&search_type=count' -d '{
  "query": {
    "term" : {
      "relation" : "friend"
    }
  },
  "facets" : {
      "popular" : {
          "terms" : {
              "field" : "user_id_2"
          }
      }
  }
}'
```

Please, note that due to distributed nature of facets calculation, counts reported by the facet query might be lower than the actual number of records if multiple shards are used. See [elasticsearch issue 1832](https://github.com/elasticsearch/elasticsearch/issues/1832)

EDIT:

There are two solutions for the edited question. One solution is to use facet on two fields:

```
curl -XPUT http://localhost:9200/relationships -d '{
    "mappings" : {
        "relation" : {
            "_source" : {"enabled" : false },
            "properties" : {
                "user_id_1": { "type": "string", "index" : "not_analyzed"},
                "relation": { "type": "string", "index" : "not_analyzed"},
                "user_id_2": { "type": "string", "index" : "not_analyzed"}
            }
        }
    }
}'
curl -XPUT http://localhost:9200/users -d '{
    "mappings" : {
        "user" : {
            "_source" : {"enabled" : false },
            "properties" : {
                "user_id": { "type": "string", "index" : "not_analyzed"}
            }
        }
    }
}'

curl -XPUT http://localhost:9200/users/user/1001 -d '{"user_id": 1001}'
curl -XPUT http://localhost:9200/users/user/1002 -d '{"user_id": 1002}'
curl -XPUT http://localhost:9200/users/user/1003 -d '{"user_id": 1003}'
curl -XPUT http://localhost:9200/users/user/1004 -d '{"user_id": 1004}'
curl -XPUT http://localhost:9200/users/user/1005 -d '{"user_id": 1005}'
curl -XPUT http://localhost:9200/relationships/relation/2001-friend-1002 -d '{"user_id_1": "2001", "relation":"friend", "user_id_2": "1002"}'
curl -XPUT http://localhost:9200/relationships/relation/2002-friend-1002 -d '{"user_id_1": "2002", "relation":"friend", "user_id_2": "1002"}'
curl -XPUT http://localhost:9200/relationships/relation/2002-friend-1001 -d '{"user_id_1": "2002", "relation":"friend", "user_id_2": "1001"}'
curl -XPUT http://localhost:9200/relationships/relation/2003-friend-1003 -d '{"user_id_1": "2003", "relation":"friend", "user_id_2": "1003"}'
curl -XPOST http://localhost:9200/relationships/_refresh
curl -XPOST http://localhost:9200/users/_refresh
echo


curl -XGET 'http://localhost:9200/relationships,users/_search?pretty=true&search_type=count' -d '{
    "query": {
        "indices" : {
          "indices" : ["relationships"],
          "query" : {
              "filtered" : {
                  "query" : {
                      "term" : {
                          "relation" : "friend"
                      }
                  },
                  "filter" : {
                      "type" : {
                          "value" : "relation"
                      }
                  }
              }
          },
          "no_match_query" : {
              "filtered" : {
                  "query" : {
                      "match_all" : { }
                  },
                  "filter" : {
                      "type" : {
                          "value" : "user"
                      }
                  }
              }

          }      
        }
    },
    "facets" : {
        "popular" : {
          "terms" : {
              "fields" : ["user_id", "user_id_2"]
          }
        }
    }
}'
```

Another solution is to add "self" relation to the relationships index for every user when user is created. I would prefer the second solution since it seems to be less complicated.

Comment: +1 for suggesting me the "Term Facets", This really would have solved the problem :), but i have some different data structure. Edited the question according to it.